# In the Abbot & Costello "Who's On First?" routine, what is the meaning of "St. Louis has a couple of days on the team?"

Tags: meaning

[Video link here](https://youtu.be/sShMA85pv8M?t=255)

When Costello's character finds out that Today is pitching and Tomorrow is catching, he remarks:

> Costello: That's all? St. Louis has got a couple of days on the team.
> Abbot:    Well I can't help that!

What is Costello trying to say? Is it something that can be translated into modern parlance? I'm generally clueless as to what he's conveying with this line.

Comment: "That's all. St. Louis has a couple of days on their team, that's all." was Costello's  explanation, according to [this website](https://pressofatlanticcity.com/test/abbott-and-costello-whos-on-first/article_5e05614e-f92a-5686-876b-cdaf69e3628e.html) i.e. Today and Tomorrow.

Comment: It's not an old use of the term days, but an absurd outcome that if two players have day names, they make up a couple (2) of days.

Answer (score 3):

This [transcript](https://www.baseball-almanac.com/humor4.shtml) refers to the New York instead of St Louis but the ideas the same.

In the skit the pitcher is named Tomorrow and the catcher is named Today. The team those has two people named like days.

> Costello: The pitcher's name?
> Abbott: Tomorrow.
> Costello: You don't want to tell me today?
> Abbott: I'm telling you now.
> Costello: Then go ahead.
> Abbott: Tomorrow!
> Costello: What time?
> Abbott: What time what?
> Costello: What time tomorrow are you gonna tell me who's pitching?
> Abbott: Now listen. Who is not pitching.
> Costello: I'll break your arm, you say who's on first! I want to know what's the pitcher's name?
> Abbott: What's on second.
> Costello: I don't know.
> Abbott & Costello Together: Third base!
> PAUSE
> Costello: Gotta a catcher?
> Abbott: Certainly.
> Costello: The catcher's name?
> Abbott: Today.
> Costello: Today, and tomorrow's pitching.
> Abbott: Now you've got it.
> *Costello: All we got is a couple of days on the team.*

Comment: When I heard that I thought that 'days' was capitalised, you know  "'Al Day and Pay Day".

Comment: @BoldBen Abbot and Costello used to do this routine like improv, and played off of each other's riffs, so you can expect any number of variations. Remember, this was vaudeville and BurleyQ, and was sometimes repeated several times a night on stage in the 30s.//"After they formally teamed up in burlesque in 1936, he and Costello continued to hone the sketch"

Comment: @BoldBen - Or Doris Day.

Comment: @Cascabel I think you might be right, in that this question is not necessarily about the English language if you see the context, but your reason that it is very clear to you seems an odd set of grounds – the whole idea of questions and answers is that what is clear to some is not to others

Comment: The thing I guess that makes it confusing to me is that with this line, he seems to understand what's going on. The gist of the skit is Costello's utter bewilderment trying to do something so simple. If he comments that there are days on the team, the bewilderment goes away because he starts to understand the names. It's strange that he would know those names and not begin to suspect that "Who" or "What" are also names. Does that seem strange to anyone else?

Comment: @Cascabel Yes, the the thing is just to enjoy the routine, not analyse all the fun out of it.

Comment: @HotLicks There's also G K Chesterton's novel "The Man Who Was Thursday" and that's only partly  humourous.

Comment: @BoldBen Not to mention Thursday Next, the female protagonist in several of Jasper Fforde's novels.